I got UE5 Packaging Error, my project is for windows. What can I do?
I am getting an error while trying to package my game for Windows and I got this. Can someone help me please, I can give more information.
********** BUILD COMMAND STARTED **********
Running: C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.2\Engine\Binaries\ThirdParty\DotNet\6.0.302\windows\dotnet.exe “C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.2\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll” VR_CyberGym Win64 Shipping -Project=“D:\diplom prace\VR_CyberGym\VR_CyberGym.uproject” “D:\diplom prace\VR_CyberGym\VR_CyberGym.uproject” -NoUBTMakefiles -remoteini=“D:\diplom prace\VR_CyberGym” -skipdeploy -distribution -Manifest=“D:\diplom prace\VR_CyberGym\Intermediate\Build\Manifest.xml” -NoHotReload -log=“C:\Users\UO-10572\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_5.2\UBT-VR_CyberGym-Win64-Shipping.txt”
Log file: C:\Users\UO-10572\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_5.2\UBT-VR_CyberGym-Win64-Shipping.txt
Platform Win64 is not a valid platform to build. Check that the SDK is installed properly.
Took 1.5850146999999999s to run dotnet.exe, ExitCode=6
UnrealBuildTool failed. See log for more details. (C:\Users\UO-10572\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_5.2\UBT-VR_CyberGym-Win64-Shipping.txt)
AutomationTool executed for 0h 0m 4s
AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=6 (6)
BUILD FAILED
